# CSS Label Textbox Layout

Tags: html, css

I've a template for a register mask. I use the `<p>` because my input boxes does not have a id only class.
It should look like in the illustration with 2 rows. I do not like extra div's, no table. Is it possible ?

**HTML (elements can be in a different order)**

```
 <div id="parent">
    <p class="Useraccount-Email-Repeat-Label"></p>
    <input class="Useraccount-Email-Repeat" type="text" />
    <p class="Useraccount-Password-Repeat-Label"></p>
    <input class="Useraccount-Password-Repeat" type="text" />
    <p class="Useraccount-Email-Label"></p>
    <input class="Useraccount-Email" type="text" />
    <p class="Useraccount-Password-Label"></p>
    <input class="Useraccount-Password" type="text" />
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried ? Show us your **CSS** or make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: nothing i just try to make better css.. for that reason i looking for a way to solve this. I don't have any css for this solution, that's why i ask.

Comment: If you are giving each input a unique class then these should be ids. You can still give all the inputs the same class, to use in the css. You could use labels rather than p's, and format them appropriately in the css. But you'll need to show SOME css to receive some help.

Comment: Why you do not want to use `table` element? By `table` you can do this so easily.

Comment: Also, you are building a form, so why not use a form tag rather than a div? Perhaps a form-table combination.

Comment: i will give labels a try, i don't like to use tables because should be consistent. Don't need to use the form tag. I handle everything in javascript.

Comment: Oh, good! So you've *deliberately* made your site unusable to those (admittedly rare) users with JavaScript disabled? Why?

Comment: It's a single page app. This make not any sense in this context. But thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
HTML:

```
 <div id="parent">
    <p class="Useraccount-Email-Repeat-Label"></p>
    <input class="Useraccount-Email-Repeat" type="text" />
    <p class="Useraccount-Email-Label"></p>
    <input class="Useraccount-Email" type="text" />
    <p class="Useraccount-Password-Label"></p>
    <input class="Useraccount-Password" type="text" />
    <p class="Useraccount-Password-Repeat-Label"></p>
    <input class="Useraccount-Password-Repeat" type="text" />
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent p,
#parent input{margin:0 2% 2%;float:left;width:48%;display:block}
#parent input{border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:3px}
```